# Python generate random: uuid v. md5 v. random which is most efficient or *inefficient*

Tags: python, performance, random

I want to generate a random short hex string (say 8-digit or 16-digit).

There are tons of options to do this eg, from the top of my head:

```
uuid.uuid4().hex[:8]
md5().hexdigest()[:8]
"{0:08x}".format(int(random.random()*1000000000))[:8]
```

What I'm wondering is if there's any reason why any of these methods **would be more efficient** than any others, or inversely if one would be **especially evilly inefficient**?

Anyone have any good oil on this?

Any suggestions for the *cheapest* way of doing this operation in python?

Comment: What are you going to be doing with these hex strings? Why is performance so important?

Comment: @JohnKugelman Just curious. I've wondered about the efficiency particularly of md5 v. uuid for a while (to store as identifiers). What prompted the Q is a toy project I only need something petty where UUID is massive overkill and ugly to slugify.

Comment: Also intuitively it seems that uuid and md5 are expensive, but may put in to another question specifically about this some other day. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Try them:

```
> %timeit uuid.uuid4().hex[:8]
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.46 µs per loop

> %timeit "{0:08x}".format(random.randint(0, 0xffffffff))
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.05 µs per loop

> %timeit binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(4))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.74 µs per loop
```

It's notable here that bits from `random` are not suitable for cryptographic purposes, so while it is likely to be the fastest that may still not be what you want.

If you're looking for crazy efficient, just get a whole bunch of random data beforehand :)

```
> randomdata = binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(1024))
> %timeit randomdata[64:72]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 101 ns per loop
```

Answer (score 7):

Best to ask for exactly what you want: 4 random bytes converted to hex. This ensures you get exactly as much entropy as you ask for.

```
>>> binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(4))
'da20d2bd'
>>> binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(4))
'3266db8e'
>>> binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(4))
'4eb079dd'
>>> binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(4))
'46e3265e'
```

As a bonus, `urandom` returns cryptographically secure random data.